# Outlook Safe Link protection trigger the actual Rest endpoint API twice

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, outlook, safelinks

There is option call Advance Thread protection (Safelink) in outlook due this when user click the URL in the mail, the actual API got triggered twice or 3 times. This multiple API triggering causing to link expired

The decoded (through https://www.o365atp.com/) URL got triggered at once.

Safelink causing the problem to get expired page.

Note- Same behaviour found when I paste the URl in team chat API got triggered in BackEnd.

Is there any better way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, don't use links that trigger by merely accessing the link. Point the link to a web page where the user needs to explicitly click on a button.

Comment: But If user would like to have of email then what to do.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean user don't want navigate another UI and doing the link trigger it require some work know. I mean to if user would like to do the trigger the link with email itself.

Comment: Any way from our end we done solutions like block the Safelink CALL(httpmethod type - HEAD)  BY doing some http request filter.